# jQuery AutoComplete display Html content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In my Asp.Net project I have use jQuery AutoComplete in one of my textbox.

It work as expected, But one problem I found in it that when I press `keydown or keyup` it show the Html content in textbox.

My Code:

```
$(".inputText").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: "/URL/Path",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ prefixText: inputvalue.value }),
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                var regex = new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + request.term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi");
                                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                    return {

                                        label: item.split('$')[0].replace(regex, "<b style='background-color: #efbc04;font-color:black;'>$1</b>"),
                                        val: item.split('$')[1],
                                        desc: item.split('$')[2]
                                    }
                                }))
                            },

                            error: function (result) {
                                alert("Error");
                            }

                        });
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $(".inputText").val(ui.item.desc);
                        __doPostBack("txtFirstName", "OnTextChanged");
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $("<li></li>")
                 .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                  .append('<a>' + item.label + '</a>')
                  .appendTo(ul);
                  };
```

[image]

Comment: I see you passing `inputvalue.value` in your AJAX yet I do not see where that is defined. I would suggest using `request.term`. Could you setup a fiddle with some example data to share?

Comment: Was able to create this following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/awo07frf/ - I think the issue is that HTML elements cannot be stored in a textbox. The element expects a String for Value. That string is not rendered. I think what you want to do is use Styling to format the text in the field and not try to use Markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the `focus` event.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/awo07frf/4/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".inputText").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: "/echo/json/",
          data: JSON.stringify({
            prefixText: request.term
          }),
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            var regex = new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + request.term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi");
            response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
              return {
                label: item.split('$')[0].replace(regex, "<b style='background-color: #efbc04;font-color:black;'>$1</b>"),
                val: item.split('$')[1],
                desc: item.split('$')[2]
              }
            }))
          },
          error: function(result) {
            alert("Error");
          }
        });
      },
      focus: function(event, ui) {
        $(".inputText").val(ui.item.desc);
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $(".inputText").val(ui.item.desc);
        __doPostBack("txtFirstName", "OnTextChanged");
        return false;
      }
    })
    .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      return $("<li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append('<div>' + item.label + '</div>')
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

You will see a few other changes that you may want to implement.